# Christoffel symbols and change of coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading section 6.3 of Manifold Theory by Daniel Martin, I don't understand the following proof.
We have two coordinate systems: $\{x^i\}$ and $\{x^{i'}\}$, then the following equation relates the Christoffel symbols:
$$
\Gamma_{j'k'}^{i'}= \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x^{j'}}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x^{k'}}\frac{\partial x^{i'}}{\partial x^i}\Gamma_{jk}^i+\frac{\partial^2x^i}{\partial x^{j'}\partial x^{k'}}\frac{\partial x^{i'}}{\partial x^i}.
$$
The proof is this:
[Proof of the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av3B7.jpg).

There is only one step I don't understand.
 In the fifth equation I don't see why you can change the $k$ for an $i$ and make it a sum, I know that $\nabla_{\partial/\partial x^j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}=\Gamma_{jk}^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, which is a sum over $i$. But then what about the term $\frac{\partial^2x^k}{\partial x^j\partial x^{k'}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$? It is not a sum. Then how does it turn into $\frac{\partial^2x^i}{\partial x^j\partial x^{k'}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, which is a sum over $i$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term

$$\frac{\partial^2x^k}{\partial x^j\partial x^{k'}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$$

is a sum (using Einstein summation notation, we are summing over the index $k$). When you sum over an index, it doesn't matter if you change the name of the index, so

$$\frac{\partial^2x^k}{\partial x^j\partial x^{k'}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k} = \frac{\partial^2x^i}{\partial x^j\partial x^{k'}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}.$$

Therefore

\begin{align*}
&\ \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x^{j'}}\left[\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x^{k'}}\Gamma^i_{jk}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + \frac{\partial^2x^k}{\partial x^j\partial x^{k'}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\right]\\ 
=&\ \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x^{j'}}\left[\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x^{k'}}\Gamma^i_{jk}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + \frac{\partial^2x^i}{\partial x^j\partial x^{k'}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right]\\ 
=&\ \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x^{j'}}\left[\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x^{k'}}\Gamma^i_{jk} + \frac{\partial^2x^i}{\partial x^j\partial x^{k'}}\right]\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh it is a sum. I forgot that when you change from one system to the other you are left with a sum. I am sorry, Einstein notation is still very new to me, thanks :)